# grammatical number agreement

Tags: grammatical-number

> You can turn men into a serial killer by brainwashing them.

I use them and men and then use a serial killer, which is singular. Is this allowed in English or not?

Comment: I don't think your comment is correct, Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it is fine

> You can turn oranges (plural) into juice (singular) by squeezing them.

> You can turn planks of wood into a table by glueing them.

But in this case it isn't meaningful, since it means you can join several men to make one serial killer... and this is practically impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Question: You can turn men into a serial killer by brainwashing them. [buzzer]

[I prefer to use examples that don't mention the word in the sample sentence].
Answer:

- You can turn **men** into **frogs** by enchanting them. [OK]
- You can turn **a man** into **a frog by** enchanting him. [OK]

If the noun is plural and the thing it is turned into is a **countable noun**, it would be plural. If the thing it is turned into is a non-countable noun, that's fine.

- You can turn aggressive **dogs** into gentle **creatures** by treating them well.
- You can turn **coffee beans** into **coffee** by grinding them. [coffee here is uncountable]